# PasteSpecial failed when copying from one table column to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the contents of one *filtered* table column to another table column while resetting the table.

I an error at the line `.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone` with the error message

> PasteSpecial method of Range class failed.

```
Sub UpdateTables()

Dim tbl As ListObject, tbl_t As ListObject

Set tbl = Sheets(1).ListObjects(1)
Set tbl_t = Sheets(2).ListObjects(1)

' Copy CUSIP of instruments (level 0)
With tbl
    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=.ListColumns("Level").Index, Criteria1:="0", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .ListColumns("CUSIP").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End With
' Reset and paste new data
With tbl_t
    .ShowTotals = False
    ' Reset table and clear non-formula cells
    If .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count > 1 Then
       .DataBodyRange.Offset(1).Resize(.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count - 1, .DataBodyRange.Columns.Count).Rows.Delete
       .DataBodyRange.Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
    End If
    ' Paste
    .ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone ' <-- CODE FAILS HERE
    .ShowTotals = True ' Used to present summized values in graph
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: If you `ClearContents` or `Delete` in between the copy & paste, you lose the copied data, you need to copy and then paste without other operations between them.

Comment: Worked. If you post an answer I can verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using copy  & paste functions you can't use any other operation in between, if you just `Copy` before the `Paste` this error won't happen.